# how to detect collision of image views in a puzzle game

Tags: iphone

i am doing a simple  jigsaw puzzle game.

for that i crop a single image into 9 pieces and display it on 9 image views.

Now i need to detect collision when one image view is comes over the half of another image view frame,

and replace image or image view each other.

how can i done can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CGRectIntersectsRect() function, it takes to CGRect's and returns YES if the rects intersect, otherwise NO.

Here is a short example:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(image1.frame, image2.frame))
{
   UIImage *temp = [[image1 image] retain];
   [image1 setImage:image2.image];
   [image2 setIamge:[temp autorelease]];
}
```

(It works of course easier if you have an array to iterate through)

Comment: Thank u justSid,i need image1 comes over image2 half of it's frame

Comment: Create a new CGRect with only the half of the size as the original frame, if they still intersect, then the half of the image is covered.